# Twitter OAuth iPhone and Navigation Controllers

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to Objective-C and iPhone programming so please bear with me. I am using the Twitter OAuth engine by bengottlieb and I can't figure out how to load the Login from a modal view or into a navigation controller.

This pushes the splash screen into the navigation controller but nothing else happens.

```
SA_OAuthTwitterController *twitterVC = [[SA_OAuthTwitterController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:twitterVC animated: YES];
```

.. so I'm thinking I have to use something like this:

```
if(_engine)return;
    _engine = [[SA_OAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initOAuthWithDelegate:self];
    _engine.consumerKey    = kOAuthConsumerKey;
    _engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;  

SA_OAuthTwitterController *twitterVC = [SA_OAuthTwitterController controllerToEnterCredentialsWithTwitterEngine:_engine delegate:self];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:twitterVC animated: YES];
```

(which does nothing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the code is running below  if(_engine)return;  ? Set a breakpoint on the [self.navigationController pushViewController:twitterVC animated: YES]; to see if its executed.

Comment: Use: if (_engine != nil) { ....... }

Comment: Okay, the code is now being executed but I am getting this warning in the console: Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x6130880>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting with Ben himself, he said the twitter engine is not designed to be loaded from a modal or navigation view. My Twitter login page is not on the main view, but on a separate view so I used NSNotifications to pass data from a second view to the engine initialized on the first view.